# Passing for count value to post datas jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops, post

Hi i'm gettings some problems using the jquery post method inside a for

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#fetch").submit(function(event) {
  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
   $.post("script.php", $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + i).done(function(data) {
    username = $(data).find(".normal").text();
    console.log(i + username); // only username is shown
   });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

With this code in the console I see only Usernames and plus i don't see them in the correct order like
Chen (username of id 3)
Test (username of id 1)
Cal (username of id 4) etc...

Any help or advice in this piece of code is really appreciated.
I'm trying to make the code really short and simple for now because later it's going to get more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER** 
your trick for delaying call for 5 seconds will work for many cases but not for all cases. cause ajax must complete in seconds otherwise problem will not solved

you can achieve this with recursion

```
function fun1 (i)
{


 $.ajax({
url: url,
data: datatobesend, // plus i value if you need to send 
async :false
})
 .done(function() {
    //your code here 
    })
.always (function()  {
 if(i==6)
{return 0}
else
{
fun1 (i+1) // this will call after first ajax call complete 
}
});
```

}

this will be fullproof as i think , you need to modify in case this may have error , i don't have tested on my site and don't require async:false

******************old Answer******************************

yes you are right it might not get in serial  , cause you are making ajax request means the request will be asynchronous to java script execution .

so it may happen that request for ID =1 will arrive late than of ID=2 so the output for ID=2 will print first than ID=1

for making them synch you will need to use jquery `$.ajax` method

**EDIT TO answer**

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
data: datatobesend,
async :false
})
 .done(function() {
    //your code here 
    });
```

keep async false will make your request synchronous, ref : [Jquery $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: After doing more search I added this to my code
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});

Now it works as I want but it stop the page process and it's deprecated

Is there a better solution? Like a time delay on each loop to prevent async without loosing the continuity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but unfortunately the rest of the page still stops its functions when making requests (and i'll need to do many more requests like 60/100) so i don't like it to stop the page and to be so slow. Also the async: false is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Is there any way to make ajax calls in an order without losing speed and page functions?

Comment: @AndreaScanu check this you might find what you want https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

Comment: Thank you for your help really, I ended up using this trick: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/delay-of-a-post-call
Basically with a jQuery trick I can delay (min 1 sec to work) each request, so they get sent all togheter but each one starts 1 sec later than the prev one, to make sure the 2nd for instance doesn't get sent before the 1st one. This way I can keep async to true and make ajax calls in my order :)

Comment: @AndreaScanu check for new answer

Comment: Thank you very much I liked your solution, i won't use it in this project because i actually need to add a time interval between each request dependinng on user input, so a default time delay of 1s is enough to have requests in order. Furthermore I also found a better way to do this using the setTimeout function, I'll write it soon for everyone having my same problem